# How to recieve an HTTPS Post request in Grails?

Tags: android, http, grails

I am writing an Android app that needs to pass data to a Grails based web application. I want to do so using a Post request on the client side. I'm not sure where to begin on the server side of things. I understand that I probably should use code that looks something like: request.getParams() but I'm not sure where this needs to go. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [controller](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllers).  e.g.

```
FooController {
    def index = {
        if (request.status == 'POST')
            print request.params
        }
    }
}
```

Now send a post to `http://<url context>/foo/index`.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, your code will be identical independent of whether the request is using HTTP or HTTPS, GET or POST.  Start with a controller:

```
class TestController {
    def index() {
        // params is a map with all the request parameters
        println params

        // do your server side stuff here
    }
}
```

For development, have your android app post to `http://<devserver>:8080/<appname>/test`.  When you deploy to a production environment, change the URL `https://<prodserver>/<appname>/test`.

If you'd like to use HTTPS in development, you can run the development server with `grails run-app -https` and grails will automatically create a self-signed SSL certificate and listen for HTTPS connections on port 8443 as well as the usual HTTP server on port 8080.